# Upload file in Blazor application

Tags: file-upload, io, blazor

I use the code below to load a file into the application directory. The file is created in the directory, but the copying of the stream to the file fails with error below

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll

```
 public async Task uploadReceipt(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
 {
     int dotFromEnd = e.File.Name.Length - e.File.Name.IndexOf(".");
     string suffix = e.File.Name.Substring(e.File.Name.Length - dotFromEnd, dotFromEnd);
     Filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + suffix;

     string appRoot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
     string relativePath = Path.Combine(appRoot, "_Receipts", Filename);
    
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(relativePath, FileMode.Create))
     {
         await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Actually the issue is that I tried to upload a pdf - the code works for text files and jpg - for this use case it is unlikely that pdf files are uploaded, but it would still be best to allow all file types to be considererd. I tried to change the stream type - but I get an error 'Property or indexer 'IBrowserFile.ContentType' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only - I guess I need to use another content type?